# Golang mgo Fetching an item by label in a nested bson array

Tags: mongodb, go, bson, mgo

I'm having trouble finding objects in a nested array. I need to find **home/away** within league array which has an events array.
Example JSON:

```
{
   "sportId":4,
   "last":266178326,
   "league":[
      {
         "id":423,
         "name":"Germany - Bundesliga",
         "events":[
            {
               "id":1125584543,
               "starts":"2020-06-07T17:00:00Z",
               "home":"SC Rasta Vechta",
               "away":"EnBW Ludwigsburg",
               "rotNum":"2601",
               "liveStatus":0,
               "status":"I",
               "parlayRestriction":0,
               "altTeaser":false,
               "resultingUnit":"Regular"
            },
            {
               "id":1125585441,
               "starts":"2020-06-10T18:30:00Z",
               "home":"Ratiopharm Ulm",
               "away":"Crailsheim Merlins",
               "rotNum":"2617",
               "liveStatus":0,
               "status":"I",
               "parlayRestriction":0,
               "altTeaser":false,
               "resultingUnit":"Regular"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":268,
         "name":"ABA - Adriatic League",
         "events":[
            {
               "id":1122419811,
               "starts":"2020-05-07T19:34:00Z",
               "home":"Test 1(Do Not Wager)",
               "away":"Test 2(Do Not Wager)",
               "rotNum":"999998",
               "liveStatus":0,
               "status":"I",
               "parlayRestriction":1,
               "altTeaser":false,
               "resultingUnit":"Regular"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":487,
         "name":"NBA",
         "events":[
            {
               "id":1120192519,
               "starts":"2020-05-01T17:00:00Z",
               "home":"Test Team B",
               "away":"Test Team A",
               "rotNum":"123",
               "liveStatus":0,
               "status":"O",
               "parlayRestriction":0,
               "altTeaser":false,
               "resultingUnit":"Regular"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

For example finding the league name "Germany - Bundesliga" I solved it by doing

```
// retrieve league by searching in the fixture collection
func FindLeagueFixture(name string) (pinnacle.Fixtures, pinnacle.League, error) {
    var fixtures []pinnacle.Fixtures

    err := db.C(FIXTURES).Find(
        bson.M{"league.name": bson.RegEx{
            Pattern: name,
            Options: "i",
        }}).All(&fixtures)
    if err != nil {
        return pinnacle.Fixtures{}, pinnacle.League{}, err
    }
```

But now I have to event home/away names within league events. For example, finding "SC Rasta Vechta". What's the best way to handle this?

I've tried something like (No regex usage yet, since I'm having trouble already. Only trying count, not doing the whole unmarshaling for now)

```
// retrieve sport team by searching in the fixture collection
func FindHomeOrAwayFixture(name string) (pinnacle.Fixtures, pinnacle.League, error) {
    var fixtures []pinnacle.Fixtures

    // find home
    c, err := db.C(FIXTURES).Find(
        bson.M{"league": bson.M{"$elemMatch": bson.M{"home": name}}}).Count()

    if err != nil {
        return pinnacle.Fixtures{}, pinnacle.League{}, err
    }

    fmt.Println(c)
}
```

Comment: You should not use mgo any more, as it is no longer supported, as heartbreaking as that is: https://github.com/globalsign/mgo/issues/371#issuecomment-527873696